# Can I install Docker package on openSUSE Tumbleweed (32-bit)

Tags: docker, opensuse, 32bit, docker-compose

#### Problem

There is a 32-bit server with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it.

According to [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/), I cannot install Docker on a **32-bit** Ubuntu:

> OS requirements
>
> To install Docker Engine, you need the **64-bit** version
> of one of these Ubuntu versions:
>
> ... Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 (LTS)

#### Possible solution

openSUSE Tumbleweed is offered for 32-bit machines. I couldn't find any documentation about whether it's possible to install Docker on 32-bit openSUSE Tumbleweed. However, looks like it's possible:

https://en.opensuse.org/Docker

Does anyone know if it's possible? I just want to make sure before installing **32-bit** openSUSE Tumbleweed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. I did it.

Install openSUSE Tumbleweed **32-bit**, then:

```
sudo zypper install docker
```

Start service and enable at startup:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Version:

```
docker -v
Docker version 20.10.6-ce, build 8728dd246c3a
```

#### Test

Docker worked fine:

```
sudo docker run --rm hello-world
```

#### Note

Some Docker images cannot be built for a 32-bit operating system, due to this error:

```
> sudo docker-compose build
...
no matching manifest for linux/386 in the manifest list entries
ERROR: ... failed to build
```